# unable to connect mac because of old version name issue

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xamarin, version

I had **xcode 9.3** in my mac which was giving me error that while I was trying  to connect from my visual studio

> version conflict.upgrade xcode to 9.4

To solve that error i have upgraded my xcode to 9.4. But now when I am trying to connect it says

> no xcode found on specified location "Applications/Xcode 9.3.

Although I have deleted xcode 9.3 and installed 9.4 successfully. It still takes path of old one automatically..

How to solve this issue.

Comment: Check your [iOS SDK locations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/questions/ios-sdk), maybe you can manually set the `Xcode` to the newly installed version

Comment: i checked it. i m unable to set it manualy.. it gets done when i pair to mac  by itself

Comment: Have you checked it from `Visual Studio`? If that's the case, you'll probably need to change the value from `Xamarin Studio` in your Mac

Comment: why xamarion studio from mac?? i am connecting it in VS ..

Comment: I think that Visual Studio saved somewhere path to your Xcode. From some reason it started to want Xcode 9.4 instead of Xcode 9.3 ( maybe you updated Visual Studio or changes some settings in Visual Studio or project you work on? ). After you updated to new Xcode and removed old one, Visual Studio can't find Xcode.. because it has old path to Xcode 9.3, and you deleted it, as you stated. I would try to find in settings something like "XCODE_PATH" or something like this and put there path to new Xcode 9.4.